# iTunes Match and syncing iOS device with iTunes Library

Tags: itunes, ios, itunes-match

Is it possible to have iTunes match turned on, on my device/itunes. And then sync songs from my iTunes Library to the device.
At the moment my internet connection is very slow, so downloading all the songs I want to listen too takes time, it would be easier if I'm near my computer to sync with a local library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no. If you are using iTunes Match, it takes over playlist and music syncing for you.

The only way to get around this currently is to disable iTunes Match on the device, and then you can do a cable or wifi sync like you have been able to do. Match just gives you access to your library anywhere, so if its smaller than the device size, you can just sync everything. Or if you don't always need that access, then just cary what you want with you. iTunes Match will still be helpful for upgrading bit rates of files, as well as if you have other machines with a better internet connection.

Finally, you can also submit a feature request to Apple at the [iTunes Feedback Page](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html). For example, make a request to do local network syncing before iTunes Match syncing if the file exists on your local network. Dropbox somewhat works this way with their LAN sync - items are synced on your network first, and then any other changes are pulled down from the 'cloud'.

Comment: +1 for good feedback advice. Sadly Apple is unlikely to implement that feature :(

Comment: Can always request :)

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that was the only option. I'll submit the feature request. Don't see why they wouldn't implement a performance feature like this, shouldn't be to hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative to what jmlumpkin said, would be to use the Share Library feature.

Of course it will only work when you're in the same network.

[image: sharing preferences]

Enable that (add a password for security) and you should see your shared library on your other computer. This has a few limitations (you can't copy the music) but at least it lets you listen to your music without the need to download from the Cloud.

Comment: You can actually copy the music if it was using Home Sharing. But again, only on same network, and at that point could just sync the mobile device.